# Event after all columns have been created in WPFDataGrid?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I want to do something after all the columns have been generated in `WPFDataGrid`.and i need the `DisplayIndex` there,so i've used the `EndInit` of `DataGrid`,but it seems the `DisplayIndex` value has not been set yet.

```
public class AdvancedDatagridControl:DataGrid
{
.
.
.
  public override void EndInit()
  {
     foreach (var column in this.Columns)
     {
        var colIndex=column.DisplayIndex; //DisplayIndex is -1
     }
  }
}
```

What Event Can i use?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the [ColumnDisplayIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.columndisplayindexchanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)? It should be raised once for each column.

Comment: I wanted to try ColumnDisplayIndexChanged,but it's not firing?why?

Comment: does it get fired when you change the column order later, after the control is fully loaded?